# how to add new text field in grid view in spring mvc when add button is clicked?

Tags: java, jsp

I want to add new record in the grid view which is getting displayed on the UI.

I m working on some project in java spring mvc.

There are some already existing records from which some are primary keys and they are not enabled at the time of editing.

So when I click on Add button, controls goes to those which field which are not primary keys means those fields are editable.

So I want to make editable primary keys at the time of adding new record.

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GetDropDownList<T>(
               string text, string value, string selected) where T : class
        {
            List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
            list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "-Please select-", Value = string.Empty });
            IQueryable<T> result = Db.Repository<T>();
            var lisData = (from items in result
                           select items).AsEnumerable().Select(m => new SelectListItem
                           {
                               Text = (string)m.GetType().GetProperty(text).GetValue(m),
                               Value = (string)m.GetType().GetProperty(value).GetValue(m),
                               Selected = (selected != "") ? ((string)
                                 m.GetType().GetProperty(value).GetValue(m) == 
                                 selected ? true : false) : false,
                           }).ToList();
            list.AddRange(lisData);
            return list;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can use primary key's display content as a Label, and for other simple text box.

Comment: But its not enough. I want in Java spring mvc. And that too the code should be generic as there are many such screens. The thing you are telling is also not possible. Because generic code is written code for jsp.
So please suggest me some other solution looking at my requirement.

Comment: post your tried code first, then will see what's went wrong.

Comment: Sorry sir I didnt try as I dont know how to do it . But when I googled I got this code. but in that code there are mistakes.

Comment: It will work for me if I add code in controller or in model. But at least I wish I could do something with your help.

Comment: Oops i m extremely sorry sir.The code which I posted is for drop down list not for adding. Its a irrelevant. Please suggest me some solution.

Comment: most welcome, nothing to worry.

Comment: Sir but I need solution.
I have model, defined some fields with the getters and setters. In model, I have annotations for each field given as name to display on UI, validation, editable. So in this editable, I have value false for the primary keys. but while at the time of adding, those primary keys field should be enable, means I want to add new record. So it should be in textable mode. Along with these, i have its Dao, service, service impl and controller. Please help me.